# Conservation of momentum in refraction

Tags: visible-light, momentum

Light, when passing through a boundary refracts.  How is momentum conserved here?  There can't be an impulse, the energy doesn't change.

Comment: ...as only the direction changes? What about velocity? Or, is the question refering to refraction in a mirror? P = m x  v. Have you found any related question? Did you consult sources on the internet? What seach did you try? I am about to set up some answer. It's a question I have; simple situation of the mirror: "optical elastic refraction".

Answer (score 1):

Momentum is conserved because the refracting medium/media at the boundary experience an equal and opposite change in momentum when the light changes speed and direction.
Light can push things - usually imperceptibly.

I'd stop there - but you did use the "how" word.

It's an electromagnetic interaction. The photon changes energy as the EM oscillations experience a change in local charge density. 
Some energy is needed for an EM wave to approach a stationary charge, climbing the electric potential.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you are assuming that you cannot have a change in momentum without a change in energy. Consider, however, what happens if a force is applied perpendicularly to the trajectory of an object: no work is done but the direction of the momentum is changed. An example of that is a planet in orbit of its star.

I am not sure that this explanation addresses specifically your question about light refraction, but it corrects a misunderstanding that motivated your question.